# Hitting search button in website with no id

Tags: vba, excel, dom

I'm putting together a VBA where it will search a firms name into a website and search it. 
The problem is that I can't seem to get my code right to hit the search button

Code:

```
Sub SearchBot()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim result As String

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "https://website.com"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    objIE.document.getElementById("SearchTopBar").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

    'click the 'go' button; This line below is what is causing the problem
    objIE.document.getElementByClassName("iPadHack Tmbsearchright").Click

    ' this line is what the button in the website is referencing
    'a class="iPadHack tmbsearchright"onclick="document.forms['hello2'].submit();"> </a

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

Comment: try just using one class, like Tmbsearchright

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work.

I got the error: 

"Run-time error '438:

Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Make 2 lines: `Set oNode = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("Tmbsearchright")(0)` and `oNode.click`. Note that `.getElementByClassName` is wrong syntax. Or you may try another way: `Set oForm = document.forms.item("hello2")` and `oForm.submit`

Comment: Nathan, got the same 438 error.

Omega, I tried your 2nd code: get error 424: object required 

1st code: error 438: object doesn't support this property/method

Sorry, this is my first time actually coding from scratching in VBA.

Comment: Got it! Thanks guys.

For those that are curious, I used:
set oNode = objIE.document.getElementsbyClassName("iPadHack tbmsearchright")(0)

oNode.click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Thanks guys. For those that are curious, I used:

```
set oNode = objIE.document.getElementsbyClassName("iPadHack tbmsearchright")(0) 
oNode.click
```